# Passing API Key

Tags: reactjs, api, api-key

I'm a new developer and I'm having a problem with passing an API key to another page.

I'm making an app, with React, where you log in on one screen, and after you are authenticated you are routed to another page where you can upload files.

Authenticating on the first page and routing works, however, on the second page you need to contact the API to upload a file, but, the API key that is obtained on the first page is not being passed onto the second page.

Does anyone know how to transfer the API key to the second page so the user still has authentication to interact with the API?

Comment: I'm hoping this "key" you talk about isn't a private API key but something along the lines of a JWT. That being said, you can use something like React's Context API, or even local storage, to store the key and have it shared between pages

Comment: Typically you'd use a *cookie* for this, so the browser adds it to every request to the backend.

Comment: try to use Context API ,

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by passing authentication key as a prop to second page(the component you are calling) like this

```
<SomeComponent authKey={key}/>
```

and access that key on second page(component) using props ( props.authKey )